# Transformation Matrix of a dot product transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let **v** be a arbitrary vector in R3 and T(**x**)=**v**.**x**. What is the matrix of the transformation T in terms of the components of **v**? It seems like trying to figure out the matrix using the equation T(**x**)=A**x** does not work, as the left side is a scalar, and the other side is a matrix. Any ideas?

Comment: hint - matrix multiplication is a dot product of rows and columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot product can be rewritten in terms of matrix multiplication, which gives you $v.x = v^\mathrm{T}x$, hence $A=v^\mathrm{T}$ and $T(x) = v^T x$.